# eclipse + WDT + liberty: how to configure eclipse to not create the "WebSphere Application Server Liberty" project?

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty, ibm-wdt

We are using eclipse + WDT + WebSphere Liberty profile.
WLP runtime is installed in some location and we create the WLP server in a different location (ie not in `<wlp_home>\usr\servers`)
To do this:

- we create a "generic" eclipse project in the workspace to be the home of the WLP server
- in the eclipse preference `"Server -> Runtime Environments -> WAS Liberty"`, `"Advanced Options"`, we add a `"User directories"` pointing to the project previously created in the workspace
- when creating the server, we specify that "user location" and everything is fine  and works well, teh WLP is created in the generic project.

The problem is that each time we start eclipse on the workspace, a project called `"WebSphere Application Server Liberty"` is created in the workspace.
This project points to the `"<wlp_home>\usr"` directory that we don't use. It is just useless for us as the WLP server is not held there .

Q: how to avoid the creation of this useless/annoying project?  In the preference? in the server? or ..?
("Closing" the project is not even a mitigation solution as it is "reopened" each time eclise starts..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WDT always keep the default user directory under the liberty installation location to ensure that there is at least one user directory available for a given runtime. And the tools does not currently allows you to remove that default user directory.  Therefore, the project will get created every time when you restart the workspace if it does not already exist.  If you want the ability to remove the default one, feel free to submit a feature request for that function.

The alternative is that you can use Working Set to filter out the project if you don't want to see it on your project explorer as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: RFE done: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=99910

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to prevent the creation of the project, however if you add the projects you actually care about to a working set, you can effectively hide the folder you don't want to see.

Click the triangle in the package explorer tab heading and click Select Working Set, then New..., then Resource, and then add all your projects to it. Click finish, and then make sure the "Selected Working Sets" radio button is selected and put a check mark next to your working set. Eclipse should be smart enough to add new projects you create to the current working set, but just make sure to verify it is or they won't show up until you add them.